# How to get drop down list to validate during postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

Well, I found the problem I was facing with the post back earlier. Somehow it turns out that drop down list, is failing event validation in all the pages. It wasn't failing validation earlier, so no idea what happened.

Anyway, now I have some 400 pages where this thing is happening. So, adding some code in all of them is out of question. So, now I want to know what I can do to get the drop down list considered as valid during the postback? Adding update panel is out of question as I will have to do it on oh so many pages.

Edit:

More details:

I have an application created in .Net 1.1. I ran the upgrade wizard in VS to upgrade to VS2012. Since then, I am finding a lot of bugs when post back happens. I had two functions for handling click event for buttons. The javascript function (used for validation) is fired properly, but the asp function wasn't called at all.

So, last week, I set eventvalidation to false, and everything worked. After reading more about it, I realised that postback was failing validation check. I checked eventtarget attribute, but that was null. So, I kept looking further. After a lot of head scratching, I finally found the culprit of that postback failure.

In that application, we add items to the dropdown, based on database query results. So, it is modified on run time. The script modifying the control is added to "ClientScriptManager", but that doesn't work. So, right now, my code has some 400 forms with dozens of dropdownlist created in runtime.

I have to get these dropdownlist removed from postback validation, or somehow return true for the validation. And that's where lies the problem. I have no idea how to do this.

P.S. Do let me know, which piece of code I should add here, if needed.

Comment: Can you put some code sample that can create scenario you explain

Comment: You need to add details about the issue to the question. Each question should be "self contained". If you have an older question for which you found the answer yourself, add an answer to that question, then add as much details about the new problem to this new question. As it stands now, we have NO idea what you are talking about in this question.

Comment: Added details in question.

Comment: Seems like you have a big task ahead to fix all these. See [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/21/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument-again.aspx) for a possible workaround. The reason it worked before is that `eventvalidation` seems to have been introduced in .Net framework 2.0. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Hmm. Oh well, might as well get down to it. Thanks for the article.